# capture value to-be-moved in functor

Tags: c++, move-semantics, functor, rvalue

Given a functor which is supposed to move a value somewhere else, what is the correct way of capturing the "moved" value?

```cpp
template<typename TYPE>
struct MovingFunctor {
  MovingFunctor(TYPE & moveto, TYPE ?? moved) : destination(moveto), capture(???(value)){}
  void operator()() {
    destination= std::move(capture);
  }
  TYPE & destination;
  TYPE ?? capture;
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<double> aValue;
  auto anotherValue = std::make_unique<double>(1);
  MovingFunctor<std::unique_ptr<double>>(aValue,std::move(anotherValue))();
}
```

Basically, what should I put instead of "??" and in which situation?

The example is a simplified version of the actual case that I have which involves `boost::variant` and `boost::apply_visitor`, so I guess I should stick with the functor-style.

The functor is built as rvalue and pass to `boost::apply_visitor`. I am not sure yet, but it may throw due to bad_get so maybe I need to do something with failed-to-move.

```cpp
  try{
    boost::apply_visitor(MovingFunctor<std::unique_ptr<double>>(destination,std::move(moved)),...);
  }catch(boost::bad_get){
    //... do something with failed-to-move "moved"
  }
```

I use c++11, so no templated lambdas.

Comment: BTW, those kind of functor are strange, as calling them twice would use a moved from object.

Comment: `??`-> Empty or `&&`, `???` -> `std::move`, `??`->Empty seems fine.

Comment: My answer would depend on this - **after** the functor is constructed, and **before** the `operator()` is called, does the functor **own** the object being moved?  Or is the calling code expected to continue owning and not leaking it?

Comment: @DrewDormann right, edited

Comment: @Jarod42 as I said, the interface is somewhat dicated by boost::variant and I have c++11. Normally the functor is built on-the-fly (as rvalue) and immediately destroyed after use. In c++17 I would have probably used a templated lambda.

Comment: @DrewDormann see previous comment. In my situation I do something like ```boost::apply_visitor(MovingFunctor(std::move(valueToMove)),...)``` so the functor does not survive too much. However, apply_visitor may throw because of wrong cast, so maybe I explicitely need a && to recover the failed-to-move value.